# Discrete Random Process Can instance average be greater than global average?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random

Assume that I am observing samples of a random variable I am interested in on a daily basis. For now, assume that number of samples I observe daily is fixed to some $K$. After a period of N days, I take the samples across all days estimate the mean. Also, I calculate a daily average. Is it possible that daily average is higher than the mean for most of the days?
PS: This question is not clearly thought out. Please feel free to point out the issues.

Comment: For one, you speak of "observing samples of a random variable I am interested in on a daily basis" and then that "the number of samples I observe daily is fixed." The first suggests that you are observing a sample once per day while the second suggests that you are observing samples multiple times per day, which is confusing.

Comment: Yes. Consider the case where all your observations are equal to 10 except one, which is lower, say 5.

Comment: @Math1000 have corrected the question